# jQuery Slider FadeIn()

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

Am working on a banner with fadeIn/fadeOut transition. Its simple realy. On intervals the images change randomly. All that works fine.

The issue is with the fadeOut part. the current displayed image wont fade out. ANY SUGGESTIONS :) ?

any if there's any kind beings out there who can give tips on how to refactor the js code for me.... am still a junior and for this project i did not want to use any plugins.

```
$(function () {

        var myPix = [ 'img/1.jpg', 'img/2.jpg', 'img/3.jpg', 'img/4.jpg', 'img/5.jpg', 
                                    'img/6.jpg', 'img/7.jpg', 'img/8.jpg', 'img/9.jpg', 'img/10.jpg',
                                    'img/11.jpg', 'img/12.jpg', 'img/13.jpg' 
                                ],
                randomNum = Math.floor(( Math.random() * myPix.length )),
                aa = '<img src="' + myPix[randomNum] + '" />';

        $('header').append($(aa).fadeIn(1000));

        setInterval( function () {
            var myPix = [ 'img/1.jpg', 'img/2.jpg', 'img/3.jpg', 'img/4.jpg', 'img/5.jpg', 
                                        'img/6.jpg', 'img/7.jpg', 'img/8.jpg', 'img/9.jpg', 'img/10.jpg',
                                        'img/11.jpg', 'img/12.jpg', 'img/13.jpg' 
                                    ],
                    randomNum = Math.floor(( Math.random() * myPix.length )),
                    aa = '<img src="' + myPix[randomNum] + '" />';

        $('header img').fadeOut(5000).replaceWith($(aa).fadeIn(2000));

        }, 6000);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/simomultimedia/vVyph/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `fadeIn()` inside of the `fadeOut()` callback function:

```
$('header img').fadeOut(5000, function() {
    $(this).replaceWith($(aa).fadeIn(2000));
});
```

#### [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vVyph/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
 $('header img').fadeOut(5000, function(){$(this).replaceWith($(aa).fadeIn(2000))});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the fade in in the complete function of the fade out, so it will only be started after the fade out:

```
$('header').append($(aa).fadeIn(1000));
    setInterval( function () {
        randomNum = Math.floor(( Math.random() * myPix.length )),
        source = "http://nunstoprecords.co.za/"+myPix[randomNum];
        $('header img').fadeOut(2000, function() {$('header img').attr("src",source).fadeIn(2000)});
    }, 5000);
```

Also, if you want to fade in and out them at the same time use two image container.